# How Clone method of java is useful in this legacy code

Tags: java, cloning

Was going through one legacy code and found the use of clone method, but not sure that how it helps in this scenario.

Below is the code snippet for the same:

The record HashMap is iniltialized in below class and will be accessed in another class that is StudentInformation.

```
public class LoadStudentRecord{

private static HashMap<String,StudentRecord> record = new HashMap<String,StudentRecord>();

private final static ReentrantReadWriteLock accessLock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock(true);
private final static Lock readLock = accessLock.readLock();
private final static Lock writeLock = accessLock.writeLock();

public static void initialize(){
//initializes the hashmap record
}

public static getRecord(String keyVal){

readLock.lock();
        try{
            return record.get(keyVal);
        }finally{
            readLock.unlock();
        }
}
```

Now there is a StudentInformation.class as shown in below code snippet which accesses the HashMap from above class and uses clone method:

```
public class StudentInformation{

private StudentRecord getStudentRecord(String studentId){

StudentRecord record = LoadStudentRecord.getRecord(studentId).clone();

return record;
}
```

So how clone is helping in above example?

Comment: It ensures that the real StudentRecord in the map is effectively read-only, at least when accessed like this.

Comment: could you please explain?